# Unique/distinct in laravel foreach

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, distinct

In laravel, I have a dropdown select box with some values, but my foreach loop around the box is showing every instance of `$psku->frame_desc`, as it should. However, I want it to only show distinct values.

Here's the code:

```
<select style="margin-top:10px; max-width:200px;" >
<option value="" selected data-default>Sort by type:
</option>
    @foreach ($orderFormData->pgroups as $pgroup)
      @foreach ($pgroup->pskus as $psku)
        <option value="{{ $psku->frame_desc }}">{{ $psku->frame_desc }}</option>
      @endforeach
    @endforeach
```

What's the best way to declare distinct or unique values within a foreach like this in laravel?

Comment: Can you post the php part where you get/fill the `$orderFormData->pgroups`

Comment: You should not do that in `view` instead do it in `controller` or better/if in database query

Comment: This is beside the point somewhat, but all the options don't really have the same value, do they?

Comment: @JTC The only problem with that is we use it everywhere else where we want each instance. However, for these sorting functions we only need the distinct version so that we can filter what shows on the view

Comment: well than for this you should create another array with unique values specially for this view

Comment: @Don'tPanic No, but for type of furniture it shows 20 instances of sofa, 23 of chair, etc. Where it only needs one of each

Comment: @TomN. yeah, I get that, but I meant the actual value parameter `value="tea"`. Seems like it would use something from `$psku`.

Comment: Oh no, that's just for testing on this one, I've changed the values. I changed it to reflect my code

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming these are collections, you can do:

```
@foreach ($orderFormData->pgroups as $pgroup)
  @foreach ($pgroup->pskus->unique('frame_desc') as $psku)
    <option value="{{ $psku->frame_desc }}">{{ $psku->frame_desc }}</option>
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-unique)

If they are not collections, you can make them collections:

```
@foreach ($orderFormData->pgroups as $pgroup)
  @foreach (collect($pgroup->pskus)->unique('frame_desc') as $psku)
    <option value="{{ $psku->frame_desc }}">{{ $psku->frame_desc }}</option>
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Unfortunately they are not, but this may help push me in the right direction

Comment: Oh thank you. It seems to load fine with that, but is still loading each instance unfortunately. I may need to read up on the collection documentation some more

Comment: What is the type of `$psku`? Is it a custom class?

Comment: Yes, we have a data php file that collects everything from our database and created variables and classes from that to build our order forms